# useEffect (with depencies from redux useSelector hooks) into custom hooks it's trigger on every import

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm new in react native world and i'm on a new project with store (manage by redux).

I encounter an issue with custom hooks and useEffect

here my custom hooks

```
const useTheme = () => {
  const [activeTheme, setActiveTheme] = useState();
  const { id: universID, defaultTheme: universDefaultTheme } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.univers
  );
  const { theme } = useSelector((state) => state);
  const { themes: activeThemes } = useSelector((state) => state.settings);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  //set theme when univers change
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('TODO TOO MANY CALLS!!!!!', universID);
    if (universID) {
       setTheme(
         activeThemes.find((theme) => theme.univers === universID)?.theme
       );
    }
  }, [universID]);

  //get active theme of current univers
  useEffect(() => {
    setActiveTheme(
      activeThemes.find((theme) => theme.univers === universID)?.theme
    );
  }, [activeThemes]);

  ... rest of code ...

  return {
    theme,
    activeTheme,
    setTheme,
  };
}
```

on components i use

```
  const {
    theme: { colors },
  } = useTheme();
```

My issue is that on every import the useEffect(()=>{},[universID]) is trigger. UniversID come from redux store.

If i understand clearly when i import useTheme() the reference of universID change because there are copy of universID from store created, and reference change.

if i pass universID as arguments to useTheme hooks there are no problem, cause reference is the same. But if i do this i need tu make a useSelector(universID) on every components who import useTheme hooks.

1. My understanding of mecanism is good ?
2. There are a way to get universID from store with the same reference on every import, for not trigger useEffect(,[universID]) on every import ? without pass universID as arguments of useTheme (i.e. useRef, useCallback) ?

Thanks for the time past to read (or better, to answer ;))

Comment: Maybe context meets your requirements more than hooks (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context)

Comment: context is for share state, like redux  no ?

Comment: Hi @bug00, I ran into the same problem with you. Did you find any solution? The only way I can think of is to move useEffect to the screen component